# Too many callouts: 11 in DataBase.Batchable

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i have a code segment in my DataBase.Batchable

```
if(pageToken!=null)
           deleteEvents(accessToken , pageToken,c.CalendarId__c);

        }
```

and delete event function code is

```
public static void deleteEvents(String accessToken,String pageToken,String CalendarId){
    while(pageToken != null)
{   String re = GCalendarUtil.doApiCall(null,'GET','https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+CalendarId+'/events?pageToken='+pageToken,accessToken);
                System.debug('next page response is'+ re);
                 re = re.replaceAll('"end":','"end1":');
re = re.replaceAll('"dateTime":','"dateTime1":');  
  JSON2Apex1 aa = JSON2Apex1.parse(re);
   List<JSON2Apex1.Items> ii = aa.items ;
  System.debug('size of ii'+ii.size());
  pageToken = aa.nextPageToken ;
 List<String> event_id =new List<String>();

           if(ii!= null){
           for(JSON2Apex1.Items i: ii){
           event_id.add(i.id);
           }
           }
  for(String ml: event_id)
  System.debug('Hello Worlds'+ml);
            for(String s:event_id)
       {
       GCalendarUtil.doApiCall(null,'DELETE','https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+CalendarId+'/events/'+s,accessToken);

       }

 }   
    }
```

because there were nearly about 180 event thats why i am getting this error but for deleting them i have an option that i create a custom object and a text field (id of event)in it and then create one more Database.Batchable class for deleting them and pass it as a batch of 9 or any other method so that i am able to do more than 100 callouts with in an  Database.Batchable interface??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 is the max. And it doesn't seem like Google's calendar API supports mass delete.

You could try chunking your batch job (the size of list of records passed to each `execute()` call). For example something like this:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Event]); // anything that loops through Events and not say Accounts
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
    // your deletes here
}

Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchClass(), 10); // this will make sure to work on 10 events (or less) at a time
```

Another option would be to read up about daisy-chaining of batches. In execute you'd be deleting up to 10, in `finish()` method you check again if there's still more work to do and you can fire a batch again.

P.S. Don't use hardcoded "10". Use `Limits.getCallouts()` and `Limits.getLimitCallouts()` so it will automatically update if Salesforce ever increases the limit.

---

In a trigger you could for example set up 10 @future methods, each with fresh limit of 10 callouts... Still batch sounds like a better idea.

Comment: please reply to this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937319/have-uncommitted-work-pending-please-commit-or-rollback-before-calling-out

Comment: One caution with attempting the maximum number of callouts (10 currently, more as limits are relaxed in the future) is that there is also a maximum amount of *time* per execution context that Apex will permit for callout operations in general. So although you might have 10 callouts that are allowed in total, you might have already burned up your total callout time (120 seconds) in the current context, if one or more callouts took longer than expected, for example. When using batch Apex for this purpose, it doesn't hurt to set your batch size to 1 record each.